# jQuery group of radio buttons .change method

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm working with a form with a radio button which is part of a set of radios and just one can be selected at a time(no problem with the single selection). One of those radios must fire a code each time it's selected a diferent code when it is unselected (another radio is selected), im using `.change` method and it fires the code when you click it, but not when it looses the selection. What i want is to toggle or be able to know when it looses the selection.

I could do it adding code to the other radios `.change` method but there are many sets of radios and it would be painful, i'm looking for a one time config.

**Edit**

The markup is made of ASP MVC Razor engine like this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeModel, new { @class = "special-radio" })
@* Other radios but without the 'specia-radio' class *@
```

js:

```
// logging
$(function(){
  $('.special-radio').change(function(){
    console.log('change');
  });
});
```

The string change only appears when you click the 'special-radio' radio.

Answer (score 4):

There is no event triggered when a radio is unchecked, because it would be redundant. Try this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmartiro/g4YqD/1/

It puts a change event on the set of radios and just fires one event if the selected radio is special and another event otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't fit perfectly into my problem because i've got multiple groups of radios, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: You can use `$('input[name=foo]')` if you want to single out one set.

Answer (score 3):

If adding a class for is not possible. You can use a container with identifier for these radio buttons. This way you can isolate the change event. 
[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cTDw9/62/)

```
var prev_data;
$('#special_radios input').change(function(){
    var me = $(this);
    //running function for check
  $('#log').html('<p>firing event for check: '+ me.attr('id') +'</p>');
    if(prev_data)
      uncheck_method(prev_data);  
  prev_data = me;
});

//@param obj = jquery raidio object
function uncheck_method(obj){
    $('#log').append('<p>firing event for uncheck: '+obj.attr('id')+'</p>');
    obj.prop('checked', false) 
    //console.log($('#special_radios input:checked'));
}

​
```

html

```
<input type="radio" name="zz" id="5"/>
<div id="special_radios">
   <input type="radio" name="rx" id="1"/>
   <input type="radio" name="ry"  id="2" />
   <input type="radio" name="rz" id="3"/>
   <input type="radio" name="ra"  id="4"/>
</div>
<div id="log"></div>
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
var newValue; // vale of checked radio button
var oldValue; // value of unchecked radio button

$('.special-radio').change(function(){
    oldValue = newValue;
    newValue = $(this).val();
});
```

If oldValue and newValue are same that means hasn't unchecked.